# What's difference between "$.FunctionName()" and "FunctionName()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the difference between a jQuery function

```
$.FunctionName = function(){ alert('Hello!') }
```

and normal javascript function?

```
function FunctionName(){ alert('Hello!') }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former becomes a static method of the jQuery object.
The latter becomes just a regular function.

The only difference, really is the owner of the function. The jQuery object/constructor owns the first method, while the `window` object owns the second method, assuming it wasn't defined  in another function scope.

Generally, you do not usually do the first one unless you want to attach a specific method that's related to jQuery. If you have a custom application specific function do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant differences. Both functions will work the same.

If you want to create you own functions library, better way is create new class (named not $) like
`my_lib={}` and then add functions to it like

```
my_lib.FunctionName = function(){ alert('Hello!'); }
```

Or

```
my_lib={
    FunctionName: function(){ alert('Hello!'); }
}
```